# How to declare and get an output parameter in store procedure in Django?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, stored-procedures

I am trying to work with store procedures. So far I am able to work with input parameters and is successfully able to retrieve records or insert etc. Now, I have a store procedure that requires an output parameter `@Id`. The goal is to insert a record in the database using the store procedure which I am able to that.

The issue, however, I am facing is that I am not being able to get the `@Id`. I am using MsSQL database. I have tried various ways to get the @Id output, but it gives an error.

This is the code:

```
cursor.execute("DECLARE @Id int; exec proc_jobcardInsert @Id = @Id OUTPUT, @Stocknumber='"+Stocknumber+"', @Modalnumber='"+Modalnumber+"'")
cursor.fetchone()
```

I have also tried it like this:

```
cursor.execute("exec proc_jobcardInsert @Stocknumber='"+Stocknumber+"', @Modalnumber='"+Modalnumber+"'")
cursor.fetchone()
```

And I also tried `cursor.fetchone()[0]`

All of them are not working. I also one or two other things but all gives me an error stating:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query`

Data is being inserted into the database but I want the `@Id` at the end. Please guide me as how to achieve it and what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Careful, you aren't using *any* parameters in your python there, just blind injection. That is a *huge* security vulnerability.

Comment: @Larnu `cursor.execute("sp_mystoreprocedure @var1=1, @var2=?", [var1, var2])`, would this be a good approach? and what output parameter

Comment: Have you read the pyodbc documentation [Calling Stored Procedures](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures) yet? It demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried but didn't able to run

Comment: @AlwaysLearning so I was able to do it, the store procedure that was implemented was set `SET NOCOUNT OFF`, Just changed it to on, `SET NOCOUNT ON`.